# Does compiler generated copy constructor/assignment renders it's parameter with const/volatile

Tags: c++, constants, compiler-generated

There are some functions which compiler could implicitly define for us in case of need and if they can be properly defined for that class. Like

- default constructor
- copy constructor
- assignment operator
- destructor.

So, whether compiler generated copy constructor/assignment takes it argument as `const-reference` OR `non-const-reference`.

```
class Test
{
  public:
    Test(const Test&);      << _1
    Test(Test&);            << _2 
};
```

If it does then what are the guiding factors for that decision.

Comment: The rules for the implicitly defined copy constructor [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) might help. It is, according to the link, either `const Test&` or `Test&` depending on the copy constructors of the parents of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules in the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) Pradhan supplied in the comments can be intuitively understood as follows: the compiler will **try** to define a copy constructor with argument `const T&` **if possible**; if not then it will **try** to define a copy constructor with argument `T&`; and if that is not possible either, then the copy constructor will be defined as deleted.

When an object of class type `T` is copied, its base classes and non-static data members must be copied too. So if one of these, say, `U` has a copy constructor that takes `U&` instead of `const U&`, then it's a no-go if `T`'s constructor takes `const T&` since all subobjects will then be cv-qualified too, and you can't obtain the `U&`. Consequently the compiler has to give up on making a copy constructor that takes `const T&`, and goes with `T&` instead. And similarly, if some base class or non-static data member **can't** be copied, then it makes sense for the compiler to generate a deleted copy constructor for `T`.

For copy assignment operators the rules are basically the same, except the compiler looks for the copy assignment operators of the base classes and non-static data members (rather than their copy constructors), and copy assignment operators are allowed to take their arguments by value (unlike copy constructors).